# how to convert a matrix to a diagonally dominant matrix using pivoting in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Hi I am trying to solve a linear system of the following type:

```
A*x=b, 
where A is the coefficient matrix, 
x is the vectors of unknowns and 
b is the vector of solution.
```

The coefficient matrix (A) is a n-by-n sparse matrix, with even zeros in the diagonal. In order to solve this system in an accurate way I am using an iterative method in Matlab called bicgstab (Biconjugate gradients stabilized method).

This coefficient matrix (A) has a

```
det(A)=-4.1548e-05 and a rcond(A)=  1.1331e-04.
```

Therefore the matrix is ill-conditioned. I first try to perform a scaling and the results where:

```
det(A)= -1.2612e+135 but the rcond(A)=5.0808e-07...
```

Therefore the matrix is still ill-conditioned... I verify and the sum of all absolute value of the non-diagonal elements where 163.60 and the sum of all absolute value of the diagonal elements where 32.49... Therefore the matrix of coefficient is not diagonally dominant and will not converge using my function bicgstab...

I am looking for someone that can help me with performing a pivoting to the coefficient matrix (A) so it can be diagonally dominant. Or any advice to solve this problem....

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

First there should be quite a few things noted here:

1. Don't use the determinant to estimate the "amount of singularity" of your matrix. The determinant is the product of *all* the eigenvalues of your matrix, and therefore its scaling can be wildly misleading compared to a much better measure like the condition number, leading to the next point..
2. your conditioning (according to rcond) isn't that bad, are you working with single or double precision? Large problems can routinely get condition numbers in this range and still be quite solvable, but of course this depends on a very complicated interaction of many factors, of which the condition number plays only a small part. This leads to another complicated point:
3. Diagonal dominance may not help you at all here. BiCGStab as far as I know does not require diagonal dominance for its convergence, and also I don't think diagonal dominance is known even to help it. Diagonal dominance is usually an assumption made by other iterative methods such as the Jacobi method or Gauss-Seidel. Actually the convergence behavior of BiCGStab is not very well understood at all, and it is usually only used when memory is a very severe problem but conjugate gradients is not applicable.

If you are really interested in using a Krylov method (such as BiCGStab) to solve your problem, then you generally need to have more understanding of where your matrix is coming from so that you can choose a sensible preconditioner.

So this calls for a bit more information. Do you know more about this matrix? Is it arising from some kind of physical problem? Do you know for example if it is symmetric or positive definite (I will assume not both because you are not using CG).

Let me end with some actionable advice which is very generic, and so not necessarily optimal:

1. If memory is not an issue, consider using restarted GMRES instead of BiCGStab. My experience is that GMRES has much more robust convergence.
2. Try an approximate factorization preconditioner such as ILU. MATLAB has a function for this built in.

Comment: Hi..
To answer some of your questions:
I am using double precision... Also when I run the algorithm for the original matrix coefficient using the bicgstab function the flag that appears is "One of the scalar quantities calculated during bicgstab became too small or too large to continue computing."
The system that I am trying to solve is about the energy and continuity equation of a gradually varied flow in a channel. The matrix that I am trying to solve is one that I created placing the elements on a certain position....

Comment: I tried the GMRES function and the system does not converge at any iteration... Can you explain me more the second recommendation? I am not so familiarly with this.... Thanks and any other recommendation let me know.

Comment: The error message you mention is very likely one of the recurrence relation parameters in BiCGStab, which unlike GMRES,CG are not guaranteed to be "reasonable" values, even if your problem is very well conditioned - but I don't know the exact algorithm being used so I can't say that is for sure the case.

Returning to ILU I think you should read more about it because I am not an expert on its use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_LU_factorization

MATLAB allows you to supply preconditioners to its solvers: see e.g the parameter "M" in http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gmres.html